# Does anyone know of a way to Shortern this and keep the same pattern going?

Tags: python-3.x

Am writing a program and wantto check exact digits for multiplication of the number 48. This method works but does anyone know of a way that could shortern this? I thought of using to power but that doesn't seem right in this instance.

```
elif amount >= 48 or amount >= 48*2 or amount >= 48*3 or amount >= 48*4 amount >= 48*5 or amount >= 48*6 or amount >= 48*7 or amount >= 48*8 or amount >= 48*9 or amount >= 48*10 or amount >= 48*11 or amount >= 48*12:
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do `amount >= 48`, the others are all superfluous.

Comment: Could you please explain? If I'm thinking correctly this will give me output for 48 or greater. However, i want to check for multiplications of the number 48 so, 48, 96 , 144 and so on. The goal is to assign each one to a different variable so if the number was 48 it would print out 1, 96 would print out 2, etc.

Comment: @RVN For what amount do you think there would be a difference?

Comment: The goal is to assign each one to a different task so if the number given was 48 it would print out 1, 96 would print out 2, etc. so basically  `elif amount >= 96: print((str)(2))` but without needing to add in  an elif statement for every amount i wish to check

Comment: @RVN No idea what you mean. Again: For what amount do you think there would be a difference?

Comment: Basically a way to automatically check for multiplications of only 48 so I don't need to copy/paste elif statements for every multiplication of the number like so:


`elif amount >= 48:
                print(self.cups[0]+(str)(self.ingredients[0])+"\n"+self.cups[1]+(str)(*self.ingredients[1])+"\n"+self.cups[2]+"\n"+(str)(*self.ingredients[2]))

  elif amount >= 48*2:
                print(self.cups[0]+(str)(*self.ingredients[0])+"\n"+self.cups[1]+(str)(*self.ingredients[1])+"\n"+self.cups[2]+"\n"+(str)(*self.ingredients[2]))`

Comment: Well that's totally different. I suggest you ask that in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print(n // 48) if n % 48 == 0  else print('not a multiple of 48')`